# Where does $\;f(z)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{z} +e^{2i \gamma}z\;$ maps the unit disk $|z|<1$ in $w$- plane? given that $0 \leq \gamma \leq 2\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Where does mapping $\;f(z)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{z} +e^{2i \gamma}z\;$ maps the unit disk $|z|<1$ in $w$- plane? given that $0 \leq \gamma < 2\pi$

**Solution i tried** - Given mapping is $$\;f(z)=\displaystyle \frac{1}{z} +e^{2i \gamma}z\;$$

we can write it as $$f(e^{i\theta})=e^{-i\theta}+e^{2i\gamma}e^{i\theta}$$

$$f(e^{i\theta})=\displaystyle e^{i\gamma}\left(e^{-i \theta}e^{- i\gamma}-e^{i \theta}e^{ \gamma}\right)$$

$$f(e^{i\theta})=\displaystyle2 e^{i\gamma}\cos(\theta+\gamma)$$

but after this i am not getting how to check its image in $w-$ plane ,because of that $\gamma$ , please help.

Thank you

Comment: What happens for $z=0$?

Comment: that will get mapped to infinity?

Comment: i think it will be easy if we can check the image of boundary , then that will give an idea about the mapping of |z|<1 ( just guessing)

Comment: I think $|z|=1$ just maps to a straight line segment at angle $\gamma$.

Comment: @copper.hat, this is what i am thinking , but i'm not getting how to prove it.

Comment: Write $z=e^{i \theta}$ and expand.

Comment: This is what i tried in solution and got stuck at $2\cos(\theta+\gamma)e^{i\gamma}$,wait if i take modulus then $|2\cos(\theta+\gamma)e^{i\gamma}| \leq 2$, from here i can get rough idea that segment can be of length $2$, but what about its inclination?

Comment: $f(e^{i\theta}) = 2 e^{i \gamma} \cos (\gamma+\theta)$. This is just the point $e^{i \gamma}$ multiplied by $t \in [-2,2]$.

Comment: so inclination is $\gamma$ because we have $e^{i\gamma}$?,

Comment: $(\cos \gamma, \sin \gamma)$ is a point on the unit circle. Multiply by $t \in [-2,2]$ and you get a segment of length $4$.

Comment: Thankyou @copper.hat.

Comment: @TheStudent If you want to avoid fighting with $\gamma$ use $$f(z) =e^{i\gamma}(u^{-1} +u),\ u=e^{i\gamma}z$$ Once you find the range of $u^{-1} +u,$ with $0<|u|\le 1$, you rotate the result by the angle $\gamma.$